# Can't Click button in Transparent Activty Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager

i am trying add an transparent activity in front of an another activity. i added the transparent activity. i want both the transparent & behind activity button's clickable. but i can click behind activity's button. but in transparent activity's button i cant click because i added one line in transparent activity that is below

```
 getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE );
```

if i remove the above line from transparent activity i can't click the button in behind activity. i need both the behind & transparent activity's button clickable. please post any suggestion. thanks...

Comment: Then why i need transparent activity? @YeahIO

Comment: Put your behind view and transparent view inside one activity.

Comment: then, everyone know this...

Comment: any one there stackoveflow?

Comment: you want to click device key or button in background activity along with your transparent activity?

Comment: Yes is this possible? @SubhalaxmiNayak if it is not possible then any other way to include views in front of another activity and both activity's views can be clickable...

Comment: its possible.. device key and transparent activity.

Comment: how? can you please post your answer @SubhalaxmiNayak